# Forloop.counter in Django

Tags: python, django, templates

```
{% for each_item in item.artifacts %}
    {% if each_item.scanner_count > 0 and each_item.scanner_match > 0 %}
        {% if forloop.counter <= 5 %}
            <tr>
            <td>{{each_item.threat_name}}</td>
            </tr>
        {% else %}
            {% if forloop.last %}
                <p><b><i> {{ forloop.counter|add:"-5" }} rows were truncated. See full report for more details. </i></b></p>
            {% endif %}    
        {% endif %}
    {% else forloop.counter -=1 %}    
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

ERROR:Malformed template tag at line 171: "else forloop.counter -=1"
I want to increment the counter only when if condition is successful. Dont know how to do it with forloop.counter. Goal is to print 5 rows of valid output(scanner count >0 and Scanner match >0)

Comment: What is `{% else forloop.counter -=1 %}  ` supposed to do, you can *not* alter the forloop counter.

Comment: I am just trying to print 5 valid output. Dont know how to control the counter @Willem Van Onsem

Comment: you can not control the `for` counter. The Django template language is *deliberately* restricted to avoid people writing business logic in the template.

Comment: That sounds like too much logic for a template for loop. I'd try to limit it to only valid items in my view. The counter's more meant for things like row numbers.

Comment: If Valid rows are more than five , I want to truncate the rest.@WillemVanOnsem

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper How would you write the logic ?

Comment: In your views, edit the `context['item.artifacts']` to only have the items you want to display

Comment: @SwetankPoddar I only want to print top 5 threat names with scanner count and scanner match >0. If there are more than 5 such threats, I want to truncate it

Answer (score 2):

You can use combination of `add` and forloop counter to achieve what you want to achieve.  But remember you need to pass some variable (I've used `rank` here for kinda storing the increment variable in template.

**views.py**

```
rank = 0 
return render(request, "base.html", {"items": items, "rank": rank})
```

**html**

```
{% for each_item in items %}
    {% if each_item.scanner_count > 0 and each_item.scanner_match > 0 %}
      {% if forloop.counter|add:rank <= 5 %}
        <tr><td>{{each_item.threat_name}}</td></tr>
        <br>
      {% else %}
        {% if forloop.last %}
          <p><b><i> {{ forloop.counter|add:"-5" }} rows were truncated. See full report for more details. </i></b></p>
        {% endif %}
      {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This is giving error: couldn't parse the remainder <=5

Comment: How comes that gives an error. That's not possible. I'm sure that above code will work 100%. Can you show me the full traceback. Or can you just copy above code completely instead of modifying your code directly.

Comment: I am initialising rank =0 and then adding that in context ={ "rank":rank} and then using ur code

Comment: Hey where are we incrementing rank value? And should not it be {{rank}}<=5

Comment: Hey there is a flaw in the code. I'm going to delete my answer. I suggest you to adjust your query filter instead of doing it in for loop.

Comment: Yeah I solved this issue. Thanks for helping though

Comment: Do you care to explain how you did that? You can also answer your own question. That will help the future readers how to solve the particular issue if they have.

Comment: So, instead of filtering the rows in template based on scanner count and scanner match. I wrote that logic in the code I wrote to parse the json. :)

Answer (score 0):

As other commenters have noted, you cannot make an assignment of the `forloop.counter` in the template, as that would be considered logic that should be in the view (controller). Remove the `{% else forloop.counter -= 1 %}` from your code and it should work as I think you intended. If not, either add logic in the object (context) being passed to the template or user other forloop attributes/variables as found in the Django documentation here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#for

Comment: If Valid rows are more than five , I want to truncate the rest@Mike Hawkins

Comment: Truncate as in not show them or show a different (shortened) version of them?

Comment: In that case, you should be able to just remove the {% else forloop.counter -= 1 %} from your code and it should work. The counter automatically updates as it iterates through the object.